# Can't print data after passing it through props in react-native?

Tags: navigation, react-native, rendering, fetch, console.log

Hey guys I am trying to pass props from one scene to another I have achieved passing props to the desired scene 
this is how basically i am changing scene through renderScene file

```
renderScene (route, navigator) {
    return React.createElement(route.component, {
      navigator: navigator, ...route.passProps
    })
  },
```

this is the code through which I am passing props

```
modalButtonPress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        component: require('../Containers/blabla').default,
        passProps: {modalData: this.state.modalData}
    });
}
```

and in other file I am calling it using this.props.modalData and props.modalData returns me with the same data

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        modalData: props.modalData,
    }
}
```

while console logging the data I can see the data in the console
[image: data received through props]

but when I am trying to print that data I can't see anything the screen is blank
here is my render method.

```
render () {
    return (
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
          <H3 style={styles.header}> {this.state.modalData._source.service_name}
          </H3>
          <Text style={styles.negativeMargin} >
              Type: <Text style={styles.bold}>{this.state.modalData._source.service_id}</Text>
          </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong in this why data is not getting render on screen.I am stuck up and confused why data is not getting print. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try props.passProps.modalData  instead of this.props.modalData

Comment: @BurakKarasoy props.passProps.modalData does not work it says cannot read property modalData of undefined.

Comment: try using props passed to constructor i.e props.modalData instead of this.props.modalData. Can you console log both and show me? Also, can you show a little more code like how are you switching scenes and stuff?

Comment: @IrfanAyaz i have updated the question and tried using props.modalData instead this.props.modalData but the result is same i am getting the object.

Answer (score 0):

Does `console.log(this.state.modalData._source.service_name)` work okay in your render method (to make sure you are accessing a valid property)?

Are you confident your layout allows your text to show on screen? No white font on white background, or zero-width view for instance? It happens a lot!

Comment: logging i can see the data in console. console.log("you are seeing modal data",this.state.modalData._source.service_name) . But can't see any data while i want to render it <View>
          <Text>{this.state.modalData._source.service_name}</Text>
      </View> i have removed all styles still can't see data.

Comment: then you more likely have an issue with your layout than your data. Removing all styles won't work/be enough. You have to put some `flex: 1` on the right `<View />` to make it grow. Try using the Inspector: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-the-in-app-developer-menu